# Imposes changing root user home directory any disadvantages?

Tags: command-line, root, users, home-directory, user-management

I have main user, e.g. `dave` with home directory `/home/dave`.
And it has lots of configs for various programs it can run like `vim`, `bash` etc.
When I login as `root` user, all my configs are not used since root has separate home directory: `/root`.

I do not plan to have any other users on my machine.
So does changing `root` user home directory to `dave` one have any disadvantages?

Comment: I believe I've install package(s) that put files in /root/; I'm guessing they weren't official packages, and whilst you could work your way around this pretty easily; I suspect it may cause problems down the road come release-upgrade time (even if I can't think of why... I'd opt for symlinks)

Comment: There is not 1 single good reason to use root over a normal user with admin permissions (ie. using `sudo -i`). And there is 1 big reason never to enable a root login: the safety of your data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, many.

- Anything you run as root which modifies configuration or state in `$HOME` will update the contents of `/home/dave`, probably causing the modified files to end up owned by root, which in turn will make them impossible for you to modify without being root (which may break some programs (`vim` and most shells being prime examples, command history will end up only usable by root).
- Anybody with write access to `/home/dave` can theoretically trivially run commands as root. Keep in mind that many CLI tools have startup files in `$HOME` that get *run*, not just parsed, when you start them. `.bashrc` and `.vimrc` are trivial examples, both of which allow anybody who can write to them to run arbitrary commands with the privileges of the user who executes `bash` or `vim` in a way that uses them.
- Some things that might be in `/root` should not be readable by any other users for security reasons. The prime example is stuff like SSH or GPG keys, but there are others. Merging `/root` with another home directory makes it much harder to ensure these secrets stay secret. Note that this is why `/root` exists at all, old UNIX systems just used `/` as root's home directory, which leaked lots of info to other users.
- Any misconfiguration in config files in `/home/dave` that makes it impossible for the `dave` user to log in will also make it impossible for the root user to log in. This makes *any* configuration changes much more risky.

Note that the second and third points are potentially serious security issues, even on a single user system. Always remember that any attack that manages to get the ability to run code as your user can do anything your user can do.

If your goal is to simply share configuration across the whole system, you can avoid all but the last issue above by using the configuration files under `/etc` instead of in home directories. These are the system-wide defaults for configuration, so modifying them modifies configuration for everyone on the system. Almost all interactive CLI tools that have some form of configuration that isn't inherently user-specific have configuration files under `/etc`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd play it safe and add per-command redirects.

You can do this in 2 ways:

- symlinking the config files one by one, for example for `vim`: `sudo ln -s /home/dave/.viminfo /root/.viminfo`
- by prepending `HOME=/home/dave` to each command. You can create an alias in your `.bashrc` file so you don't have to think about it:

  ```
  echo "alias vim='HOME=/home/dave vim'" | sudo tee -a /root/.bashrc
  ```

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would run their text editor as root."sudo -e /etc/textfile" has the same length as "sudo vi /etc/textfile", but doesn't have the problem of running the editor under the root account

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `-e` flag. To me, your first sentence comes across as arrogant and uninviting. To reach more readers, I suggest you move it to the end of your comment and make it softer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to be arrogant. I was just confused why you used an text editor as an example

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to edit files as `root`, simply use `sudoedit` (I believe it’s equivalent to `sudo -e`).

The command will open your editor on a temporary file which will replace the original on successful exit. (Vim’s `:cquit` command can be used to make exiting “fail.”)

As for the shell, I’d suggest leaving it barebones. It will remind you don’t want to be logged in as root for very long. If you must, use the `/etc` directories or other means of configuring root specifically. But do not link the files.